# Trying to create issue on redmine from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

We have a redmine server and a web application written in RoR. I'm trying to create issues from my website with the following ActiveResource object:

```
module Redmine
  class Issue < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http..."
    headers["X-Redmine-API-Key"] = "..."
  end
end
```

The server is not publicly accessible, so my API key is working well as I can get any issue doing `Redmine::Issue.find(1)`

When I try to create a new issue with the following code, it always fails:

```
Redmine::Issue.create({
  subject: "Hello, World",
  project_id: 3
})
```

With the error message "Sujet doit être renseigné(e)", which means "Subject can't be blank".

The subject is the first parameter I give to the issue, so I really don't understand where can this come from!

I'm following the [Redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_ruby).

Edit: I'm using my personal API key for the moment, so I'm administrator on the redmine

Comment: Have you tried instantiating then saving the issue? `issue = Redmine::Issue.new(subject: "Hello World"...)` then `issue.save`? Only because that's what the example shows, even though I'd think the calls would be identical from ActiveResource

Comment: I tried this at first, but as you said It's almost the same. And the result is the same anyway!

Comment: Bummer, sounds like a bug or incorrect documentation on Redmine's part.

Comment: Thanks @agmin, I found the solution and answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem comes from `ActiveResource` configuration, I have to manually add `include_root_in_json = true` in my object for the method to work.

I don't know if this is a normal behavior, but I'll comment it on redmine wiki also.

Comment: This solved it for me. Working with JSON in Python, this means wrapping the response dict in another dict with a key named "issue".

Answer (score 0):

Try https://rubygems.org/gems/redmine_client with that gem you will be able to create issues like:

```
  RedmineClient::Issue.create(
    :subject => "My Subject",
    :project_id => PROPER_PROJECT_ID,
    :status_id => PROPER_STATUS_ID,
    :description => "description goes here",
    :tracker_id => PROPER_TRACKER_ID,
    :priority_id => PROPER_PRIORITY_ID
  )
```